# Parsing different date formats in a string in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a string which can possibly contain a date in any of the following formats:

```
2001-01-05 (yyyy-mm-dd)
2001/01/05 (yyyy/mm/dd)
01/05/2001 (dd/mm/yyyy)
01-05-2001 (dd-mm-yyyy)
2001 january 5
2001 5 january
january 5 2001
5 january 2001
january 5
5 january
```

I want to be able to parse the particular string and extract the Date object from it.

My approach was as follows:

```
String[] date_formats = {
                            "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            "yyyyy/MM/dd", 
                            "dd/MM/yyyyy",
                            "dd-MM-yyyy",
                            "yyyy MMM dd",
                            "yyyy dd MMM",
                            "dd MMM yyyy",
                            "dd MMM",
                            "MMM dd",
                            "dd MMM yyyy"};

String output_date = null;
for (String formatString : date_formats)
{
     try
     {    
         Date mydate = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(token);
         SimpleDateFormat outdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
         output_date = outdate.format(mydate);
         break;
     }
     catch (ParseException e) {
         System.out.println("Next!");
     }
 }
```

This doesn't seem to work as expected. Especially for dates like 5 January 2001 etc. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: @Kayaman What is wrong with the patterns? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Always provide a locale to your date format when you want to parse date in a particular language. (`new SimpleDateFormat("{format}", Locale.ENGLISH);`)

Comment: @AlagappanRamu Nothing now that you fixed them.

Comment: @Kayaman It still doesn't work properly for dates like 5 January 2001. It satisfies the yyyy MMM dd pattern and the date I end up getting is 00100624 which is totally arbitrary.

Comment: `This doesn't seem to work as expected`. Do you get an exception or a date which does not seems good? An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Use `SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(false)`. This way it will not attempt to parse dates that aren't the exact format it wants.

Comment: Good to know but useless in this case. The OP is trying each format in a try/catch statement until the end of the try statement is met.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Useless? His problem was that in some cases the non-correct patterns were parsing the values, giving arbitrary values. A situation corrected by setting lenient to false.

Comment: IMHO, incorrect pattern will end in the catch statement and the next one will be tried.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle This has helped me in avoiding false positives when I parse the dates.

Comment: OK, I had a confusion about the meaning of lenient. +1 for Kayaman.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have all formats in the `date_formats` array for the type of format you anticipate would be coming in.

Have a look at the `SimpleDateFormat` [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Have a look at the examples in the javadocs.

```
2001-01-05      - yyyy-MM-dd 
2001/01/05      - yyyy/MM/dd
01/05/2001      - dd/MM/yyyy 
01-05-2001      - dd-MM-yyyy 
2001 january 5  - yyyy MMMMM d
2001 5 january  - yyyy d MMMMM
january 5 2001  - MMMMM d yyyy 
5 january 2001  - d MMMMM yyyy
january 5       - MMMMM d
5 january       - d MMMMM
```

Comment: I did have a look the docs. Aren't the patterns that I mentioned correct?

Comment: Yes. Your formats are wrong. I have added the formats you need.

Comment: It still doesn't work properly for dates like 5 January 2001. It first satisfies the yyyy MMM dd pattern and the date I end up getting is 00100624 which is totally arbitrary.

Comment: Setting setLenient to false as suggested by Kayaman, helped in avoiding the above error.

Comment: But your list of "date_formats" should not have MMM. There is no date in your "possibility" list (example list) to match it.

Comment: Okay... But, there are possibilities of the date being "5 Jan 2013", will the patter n "d MMMMM yyyy" be able to parse it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of testing "yyyy-MM-dd", then "yyyy/MM/dd", then "yyyy.MM.dd" (used in many countries), etc., you can start by

```
token = token.replaceAll("-|\\.", "/");
```

This way all dots and dashes are replaced with "/", and you can reduce the number of formats and tries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String[] date_formats = {
                        "y-M-d",
                        "y/M/d", 
                        "d/M/y",
                        "d-M-y",
                        "y M d",
                        "y d M",
                        "d M y",
                        "d M",
                        "M d",
                        "d M y"};

String output_date = null;
for (String formatString : date_formats)
{
     try
     {    
         SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);  
         output_date = "5 January 2001"; 
         Date yourDate = sf.parse(output_date);
         break;
     }
     catch (ParseException e) {
         System.out.println("Next!");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract String of Date by using

```
String mydate = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).format(new Date());
```

**new Date()** will return current day's date, you can change it to any date that you desire.

So if you change you code like this:

```
String[] date_formats = {
        "y-M-d",
        "y/M/d", 
        "d/M/y",
        "d-M-y",
        "y M d",
        "y d M",
        "d M y",
        "d M",
        "M d",
        "d M y"};

for (String formatString : date_formats)
    {
        String mydate = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).format(new Date());
        System.out.println(mydate);
    }
```

You will end up with these:

```
2013-10-2
2013/10/2
2/10/2013
2-10-2013
2013 10 2
2013 2 10
2 10 2013
2 10
10 2
2 10 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this date format `"dd MMMMM YYYY"` for "5 January 2001"

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateInString = formatter.format(date);

    LOG.warn("date in String "+dateInString);
```

make Sure that MM is in capital

Answer (score 0):

Kayamans answer works, this is what it looks like in a code snippet so you can easily test it for yourself (direct copy paste from my own code):

```
static String[] date_formats = {
        "yyyy-MM-dd",
        "yyyy/MM/dd",
        "dd/MM/yyyy",
        "dd-MM-yyyy",
        "yyyy MMM dd",
        "yyyy dd MMM",
        "dd MMM yyyy",
        "dd MMM yyyy"};

static String[] dates = {
        "21/02/2012",
        "21-02-2012",
        "21-2-2012",
        "21 Feb 2012",
        "Feb 21 2012",//will not be parsed
        "21 februari 2012" //Dutch
};

@Test
public void test(){
    for(String date : dates) {
        parseDate(date);
        System.out.print("----------------");
    }
}

private void parseDate(String token){
    Locale dutch = new Locale("nl", "NL");
    for (String formatString : date_formats)
    {
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString, dutch);
            format.setLenient(false);
            Date mydate = format.parse(token);
            System.out.println(mydate.toString());
            break;
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Next!");
        }
    }
}
```