# How to convert different date formats in JDK11 to dd-mm-yyyy format?

Tags: java, java-11, simpledateformat, date-format, datetimeformatter

I have a use case where I have date in the following formats,

1. 2023-05-09T05:55:07Z
2. 2023-04-30
3. 08-05-2023
4. 2023-05-09 00:00:00
5. 31-Dec-2021

Irrespective of the input format I have a requirement to convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy` format. How can I convert it in JDK11? I tried different libraries but got no luck.

Comment: Have you considered constructing a DateTimeFormatter for each format and then trying each one in turn?

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution in java the way we have in JS. just with d = new Date() & then d.getDate(), d.getMonth() .. so on

Comment: Even in JS, the input format of what you parse matters. `new Date()` is just the current date, it's not parsing anything there.

Comment: The example `08-05-2023` is quite dangerous because one cannot reliably derive if it is `MM-dd-uuuu` or `dd-MM-uuuu`. Those would both be parseable by a `DateTimeFormatter`, but the results will be significantly different.

Comment: But within new Date() constructor you can pass any date format & it will give you a generic date object which have those methods

Comment: Do not use the `java.util` package for dates. Use the `java.time` package that was introduced in Java 8. See my response below.

Comment: @DikshaGoyal *But within new Date() constructor you can pass any date format & it will give you a generic date object which have those methods* -- This is incorrect. Look at your example above. Try passing in 08-05-2023, like you showed, and see what JavaScript gives you. It will not work.

Comment: You tagged your question simpledateformat, but you should unconditionally avoid using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those clauses were troublesome and are long outdated. Do use java.time and its `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes.

Comment: Your first format unlike the others includes an offset from UTC. In which time zone do you want the date in that case? And in the other cases, do you want to use the same time zone that was understood in the original string?

Comment: This Question was closed for the wrong reason. This is not an opinion-based question. It is however a duplicate of other Questions on how to parse date-time inputs with various formats. Voting to re-open.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51587242/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19137007/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4024544/642706), and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over known formats and skip ones that throw a `DateTimeParseException`.

**Note:** If you are parsing just a date string into a `LocalDateTime`, you will need to build the formatter and specify that the time portion is optional.

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.*;

public class DateParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("2023-05-09T05:55:07Z")); // 2023-05-09
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("2023-04-30")); // 2023-04-30
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("08-05-2023")); // 2023-08-05
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("2023-05-09 00:00:00")); // 2023-05-09
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("31-Dec-2021")); // 2021-12-31
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("")); // null
    }

    public static String normalizeDate(String rawDateTimeString) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(parseDateString(rawDateTimeString))
                .map(displayFormat::format)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    private static LocalDateTime parseDateString(String dateString) {
        for (DateTimeFormatter formatter : knownFormats) {
            try {
                return LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static final List<DateTimeFormatter> knownFormats = Arrays.asList(
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME,
            dateOnlyFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            dateOnlyFormatter("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            dateOnlyFormatter("dd-MMM-yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));

    private static DateTimeFormatter dateOnlyFormatter(String datePattern) {
        // Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175568/1762224
        return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern(datePattern)
                .optionalStart()
                .appendPattern(" HH:mm")
                .optionalEnd()
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
                .toFormatter();
    }

    private static final DateTimeFormatter displayFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
}
```

Here is a modified version that is simpler as Devin suggested. It ignores the concept of time entirely, and only focuses on date when parsing. It removes the need for the `dateOnlyFormatter` method (as seen above).

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DateParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("2023-05-09T05:55:07Z")); // 2023-05-09
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("2023-04-30")); // 2023-04-30
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("08-05-2023")); // 2023-08-05
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("2023-05-09 00:00:00")); // 2023-05-09
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("31-Dec-2021")); // 2021-12-31
        System.out.println(normalizeDate("")); // null
    }

    public static String normalizeDate(String rawDateTimeString) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(parseDateString(rawDateTimeString))
                .map(displayFormat::format)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    private static LocalDate parseDateString(String dateString) {
        for (DateTimeFormatter formatter : knownFormats) {
            try {
                return LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static final List<DateTimeFormatter> knownFormats = Arrays.asList(
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME,
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));

    private static final DateTimeFormatter displayFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 I added `.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)` to the offending formatters above.

Comment: Good Answer, but this has already been covered on multiple other existing Questions.

Comment: In real work, the locale should likely need to specify a culture and possibly a sub-culture. Date-time formats (abbreviation, punctuation, capitalization) can vary across various English-speaking places.

Answer (score -1):

This method is simple and easy to decipher. Here is all that the parseDateTime function does:

1. Sets the output format
2. Sets all possible input formats
3. Iterates over each input format until the correct one is found
4. Returns the date/time in the specified output format

> **Note** If the String passed into the function is not in one of the 5 specified input formats, then it will return null. This should make it easy to see if it was successful or not!

If you need more information to help add more formats, here is the DateTimeFormatter Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE

````java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputDates = {
                "2023-04-30T05:55:07Z",
                "2023-04-30",
                "30-04-2023",
                "2023-04-30 00:00:00",
                "30-Apr-2023"
        };

        for(String date : inputDates)
            System.out.println(date + "\t->\t" + parseDateTime(date));
    }


    private static String parseDateTime(String currentDate){
        //Desired Output Pattern
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

        //All Possible Input Patterns
        DateTimeFormatter[] formatters = {
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE,
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
        };

        //Iterate over each pattern until it finds the correct one
        for(DateTimeFormatter currFormatter : formatters){
            try{
                return LocalDate.parse(currentDate, currFormatter).format(outputFormat);
            } catch(Exception ignored){
                //Current formatter did not work, so lets try the next one
            }
        }
        return null; // String was not one of those 5 formats
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please be aware that parsing month names is `Locale` sensitive; and that `Z` can stand for a time zone, not necessarily the literal `Z`

Comment: *Never* put quote marks around the `Z` in a date-time formatting pattern. The quotes mean "expect but ignore this text". Ignoring that text is restless as the presence of a `Z` means "An offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds". You are discarding valuable information, with no benefit in return. I must down-vote on a solution that recommends data loss.